# Azure DataLake Analytics U-SQL Pipeline Activities Error

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Previously we have used Author deployment for authentication, but it get disabled after 14 days of inactive, So i tried service Principal authentication but is does't work and throw the below error while running activity in datafactory

Cannot resolve DataLakeAnalyticsUri '', Please change or remove DataLakeAnalyticsUri and have a try.

{
    "name": "AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService",
    "properties": {
         "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
         "typeProperties": { 
                    "accountName": "accountName",
                    "dataLakeAnalyticsUri":"azuredatalakeanalytics.net",
                    "subscriptionId": "subscription Id",
                    "resourceGroupName": "resource Group Name",
                    "servicePrincipalId":"service Principal Id",
                    "servicePrincipalKey":"service Principal Key",
                    "tenant":"tenant id"
           }
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

**Note:** User accounts that are managed by Azure AD expires 14 days after the last slice run.

To avoid or resolve this error, reauthorize by selecting the Authorize permissions when the token expires. Then, redeploy the linked service.

---

To resolve the issue, make sure to pass the `"dataLakeAnalyticsUri":"<azure data lake analytics URI>"`.

**Example:** `"dataLakeAnalyticsUri": "azuredatalakeanalytics.net"`

For more details, refer "[Transform data by running U-SQL scripts on Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: After adding dataLakeAnalyticsUri also, its showing same error while rerun the activity in data factory

Comment: Updated the answer as per the question.